# What does that +0100 value mean in NSDate?

Tags: iphone, cocoa, cocoa-touch, nsdate

When I look at an NSDate value in the debugger, I get something like this:

1.4.2010 22:01:47 +0100

I don't get it what this +0100 is good for. Sometimes it is +0200. Is that supposed to be the time zone or something like that? What's it exactly? How does it affect the "since reference date" value?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Timezone.

+0100 means 1 hour ahead of UTC (GMT).

Comment: it's a ISO 8601 time zone designator to be precise, although the rest of the format is not in ISO 8601: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_zone_designators